# dynamic generation of GUI with the values in DB in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table in DB in which each row specifies a control in UI(for eg: textbox,label,checkbox,dropdown list etc).Everytime i load the page, i want to hit the DB, take these data and build the GUI accordingly. 
Currently i have this functionality in asp. In asp what i do is like, i hit the DB, take the values and iterate through it to check whether it is checkbox/textbox/dropdown and then i create these controls in the codebehind itself and finally add it to a panel in my aspx.
How can i achieve this functionality in MVC4?I am totally new to MVC. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

still not sure what exactly the question is, but i think this could help: Programm a Helper of your own! i wrote something simple down:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CreateDynamic(this HtmlHelper helper, string type, string name)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            default:
            case "TextBox":
                return helper.TextBox(name);
            case "CheckBox":
                return helper.CheckBox(name);
        }
    }
```

Invoke by:

@Html.CreateDynamic("TextBox", "MyTextBox")

or

@Html.CreateDynamic(Model.Type, Model.Name)